# how to toggle a template using v-show

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

i am trying to toggle the presence of the template using `v-show` or `v-if` as shown in the code posted below.

the problem i am facing is, despite `v-show` is not a lazy conditioing, when i set `showTemplate` to false or true, the content of `msg` get always displayed

please let me know how to use `v-show` and `v-if` correctly

**helloWorld**:

```
<template v-show="showTemplate">
  <div class="hello">
  {{msg}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    let showTemplate = ref(true)
    showTemplate.value=false
</script>
```

**App**:

```
template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>


</script>
```

Comment: v-show or v-if does not work in the outermost template tag. try adding the conditionals in the div with class "hello"

Answer (score 0):

U have to use like that:

```
<template>
  // v-show or v-if it doesn't matter
  <div v-show="showTemplate" class="hello">
  {{msg}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    let showTemplate = ref(true)
    showTemplate.value=false
</script>
```

Cause v-if or v-show don't work with `template` atribute.